# C#.Почему массивы-типы ссылок?

Tags: c#, массивы

Узнал что массивы в C#-это типы ссылок и они хранятся в куче,которая используется для динамичного выделения памяти.Но вот вопрос:для чего массиву динамичное выдиление памяти?.Вот например мы объявляем массив 
int[] newArray = new [4];
Мы заранее знаем что массив будет принимать 4 елемнта типа Int32 и мы заранее знаем сколько памяти ему потребуется.Так почему массивы-типы ссылок?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Сколько памяти потребуется" важно не столько при выделении памяти, сколько при хранении массива в других объектах.

Например, у вас есть класс вида

```
class A
{
   public int fieldA;
   public int fieldB; 
}
```

И есть работающий с ним код вида

```
var a = new A();
a.fieldB = 42;
```

Перед реальным выполнением этот код надо превратить в код для конкретной платформы. JIT компилятор, который этим занимается, заранее знает, сколько объект типа A занимает в памяти, и по какому смещению в нем лежит поле fieldB:

```
[0 header][+24 fieldA][+28 fieldB] // 24 - условный размер заголовка
```

и он генеренирует что-то вроде

```
mov [a + 28], 42 // положить по адресу a + смещение в нем поля fieldB значение 42
```

И все это работает быстро. Теперь добавим поле-массив (в котором может лежать массив, а может и не лежать):

```
class A
{
   public int fieldA;
   public int[] fieldArray;
   public int fieldB; 
}
```

Получаем объект вида

```
[0 header][+24 fieldA][+28 fieldArray][+32 fieldB] // размер fieldArray предсказуем, т.к. массив - ссылочный тип, и в этом поле лежит адрес массива.
```

и код при выполнении

```
mov [a + 32], 42 // положить по адресу a + смещение в нем поля fieldB значение 42
```

Ок, теперь представим что int[] - это value type.

```
[0 header][+24 fieldA][+28 fieldArray][+??? fieldB] // размер fieldArray заранее неизвестен
```

Как теперь в этой ситуации записать значение в fieldB? Реально проверять размер массива перед каждым обращением в соседнее поле? Перекомпилировать метод из IL в C# заново под каждый объект? Дорого, сложно и неэффективно. Разрешить массивы (и, соответственно, строчки) только заранее известной длины? Ну тогда на языке вообще будет тяжело что-то реальное написать :)

А вот если убрать необходимость как-то хранить массивы в других объектах - то все ок, можно делать из них value type. Именно так сделано для [структуры `Span<T>`, которая, по сути, и есть value type array](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=netcore-3.0).

Вот, выделяет 100 байт чистейшего стека, без всяких там ссылок:

```
Span<byte> stackSpan = stackalloc byte[100];
```

Answer (score 1):

На вопрос "Почему?" краткий ответ таков: потому что на данный момент так сделано.

Можно ли сделать иначе: если массив умещается на стеке - размещать его там, не умещается - размещать в куче? Да, можно. В JVM делается именно так (во всяком случае, в некоторых реализациях HotSpot). Почему не сделано в CLR? Не всё сразу. Разработчики .NET предпочли реализовывать другие фичи (значимые типы, дженерики, указатели на неуправляемую память и пр.)

Однако, работы по определению, где выгоднее разместить объекты, ведутся. [Object Stack Allocation](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/design-docs/object-stack-allocation.md). Надеюсь, эти теоретические работы перейдут в практическую плоскость.

Comment: В хотспоте вообще все массивы в стеке размещаются? И при этом остаются полноценными управляемыми массивами? Или там просто есть аналог unsafe stackalloc в c#?

Comment: @PashaPash - я весьма поверхностно знаком с этим. Знаю лишь, что JVM прямо в рантайме может оптимизировать код, размещая некоторые объекты на стеке и т. п. Это существенно уменьшает нагрузку на GC. Вроде бы это делается лишь в случае многократных вызовов некоего куска кода (метода). Также она может автоматически векторизовать математические вычисления (в .NET последних версий для этого нужно вручную юзать System.Numerics.Vector<T>).

Comment: Почитал - да, там примерно те же ограничения, что на ref struct - если объект никуда не передается, не возвращается, не попадает в поля других объектов - jvm может выделить его на стеке.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что можно сделать так:

```
int[] i;
i = new int[15];
//тут какое либо использование
i = new int[25];
//ещё что либо
n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()/*Любой другой способ получения информации от пользователя*/)
 i = new int[n];
//ещё что либо
```

А если быть более честым, то c# полностью объектно-ориентированный, и всё что в нём есть - объект, а объект - это составная сущность которая занимает (зачастую) неопределённое количество памяти.

> Мы заранее знаем что массив будет принимать 4 елемнта типа Int32 и мы заранее знаем сколько памяти ему потребуется.

Да и  тут я бы с вами поспорил. А как же вычисление значений не на этапе компиляции, а в рантайме?(во время выполнения)

Простой пример, который я часто использую: мне бывает лень объявлять масивчики и я пользуюсь таким методом(читай: отрывок паттерна Фабрика. хоть вообще не красивый, не правильный и нельзя так делать, но блин удобно)

```
GetArr<T>(int lenght)=> new T[lenght];
```

Это универсальный метод для создания Массива любого типа.

А ещё, небольшая разница между тем же самым Int32. Это не класс а структура, а структуры являются TypeValue - значениями, и соответственно хранятся в стеке, а Array является производным от Object, и соответственно располагается в Куче

Comment: судя по вашему первому примеру,возникает вопрос:а для чего для массива сначала делать ссылку,потом в куче выделять память под него?Не легче просто выделить память в стеке для него?

Comment: Ну для начала в .net абсолютно все типы являются производными от object. Разница между ValueType и ReferrenceType чисто семантическая и проявляется при присваивании и передаче параметров, которое, по сути, тоже присваивание. В случае с ValueType происходит копирование значений, в случае c ReferenceType - копирование ссылки на значение. По поводу размещения на стеке и в куче - все на усмотрение компилятора и ни как не связано с семантикой типа.

Comment: @VitalykChernysh а если придется вернуть массив из метода - предлагаете полностью его копировать? Стек же отмотается до точки вызова метода при ret.